# Custom Taxonomy not being saved on custom posttype

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

This is very unusual, and I can't seem to figure out why this is happening.

I have registered a custom posttype and a taxonomy (for that posttype). The taxonomy widget gets displayed on the "edit post" page although when I try to save a taxonomy

- The suggestions show up
- I am able to select them
- But when I hit "update" action, the page reloads but does not show the taxonomy.

Any idea why this might be happening ?

Comment: If you could please add your code, to get clear of what you're doing, Thanks